# MINI Cooper Oil Leak

Tags: oil, exhaust, leak, mini-cooper

I bought a 2007 MINI Cooper 8/27/14. On 9/9, as I drove to work, I noticed smoke coming from the back & front of the car. When I drove home late that night, the car was not smoking. After that time the car would smoke if I drove it longer distances. I have been told that oil is leaking from the vacuum pump & full flow oil filter seals onto the exhaust pipe. Why would the car only smoke on slightly longer drives rather than constantly if the oil is leaking onto the exhaust pipe? Wouldn't it leak whenever I drive and so smoke whenever I drive? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a turbo car (the Cooper S)?

Answer (score 2):

The Mini has an unusual set up on its oil filter element. If you look at the filter you will see one end has a rubber sealing on it, whilst the other end does not. When you fit the filter element, the rubber ended end must be on the outside, away from the engine and into the cap you take off to replace the element. If you dont know it, it is easy to think the rubber end goes towards the engine but it does not. Fitted the wrong way round it causes havoc with the oil pressures.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because your exhaust pipe is hotter when it runs longer, and is cold enough when not running much to burn the oil. Anyways you could buy a special paste to fill-block the leak.